# Django i cannot add button in modal for each field with ajax

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates, django-urls

I m trying to put a button in my table but i cannot succeed

i receive an error
"Reverse for 'editare-agenda' with keyword arguments '{'pk': '+field.id+'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboard/editare\-agenda/(?P[0-9]+)$']"

if i put an number  instead +field.id+ is working . if i test alert(field.id) i receive the id. is something wrong writing {% url 'dasboard:editare-agenda' pk=field.id %} but i cannot find the solution.

this is my urls.py:

path('editare-agenda/<"int":pk>', editare_agenda, name="editare-agenda"),

** "int" = int  -> i cannot write int in url path because he disappear

```
 $.ajax({
    data: values,
    method:"POST",
    url: destinatie,
    contenttType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data){
        var content ="";
        $.each(data.agenda, function(i, field){
            content += '<tr class="text-center">';
            content += '<td>'+field.denumire_unitate+'</td>';
            content += '<td>'+field.sectia+'</td>';
            content += '<td>'+field.telefon+'</td>';
            content += '<td>'+field.pers_contact+'</td>';
            content += '<td>'+field.adresa+'</td>';
            content += '<td><a href="{% url "dashboard:editare-agenda" pk='+field.id+'%}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" style="border-radius: 5px;margin: 1px;"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg" style="color: blue"></i></button></a></td>';
            content += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#tabela_agenda').html(content);
}
```

});

Comment: you cannot put id from js to django template code. You can do it like this.`http://example.com/url/?pk=1`

Comment: i don t have django forms in template i have only a table
<table>
<thead><tr><th>.....</th></tr> </thead>
<tbody id="tabela_agenda"></tbody>
</table

Comment: you should edit your url

Comment: @shourav thanks! is working..but is not the best option. ex  my current url is http://localhost:8000/dashboard/edit/1/   if i change runserver port that url will not work anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your url entry

```
path('editare-agenda/', editare_agenda, name="editare-agenda"),
```

and in template

```
content += '<td><a href="{% url "dashboard:editare-agenda" %}?id='+field.id+'"><button type="button" tclass="btn btn-sm" style="border-radius: 5px;margin: 1px;"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg" style="color: blue"></i></button></a></td>';
```

and in view

```py
def editare_agenda(request):
    field_id = request.GET.get('id', None)
     # Now you can use field id as pk
    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
content += '<td><a href="{% url "dashboard:editare-agenda" pk=field.id %}"><button type="button" tclass="btn btn-sm" style="border-radius: 5px;margin: 1px;"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg" style="color: blue"></i></button></a></td>';

path('editare-agenda/<int:pk>', editare_agenda, name="editare-agenda"),
```